# Can't get Sqoop 1.99.3 working with Apache Hadoop 2.4.0 on 64 bit Centos 6.5

Tags: tomcat, hadoop, sqoop

I have Apache hadoop working and installed on Centos 6.5 KVM virual server. It is installed at

```
/home/hduser/yarn/hadoop-2.4.0 and the config files are in /home/hduser/yarn/hadoop-2.4.0/etc/hadoop.
```

I was getting complaints from hadoop about the libraries being 32 bit (guess the binary installation contains these by default) so I did a complete source build to get the 64 bit libs. But it seems sqoop 1.99.3 will only want use the hadoop jars anyway..(?)

This is the main error it seems and it seems a popular one too but I can't find any suggestions that work. addtowar.sh is not present in my sqoop installation

```
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)**
```

Sqoop is at /home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200 and in cataline.properties :-

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/../lib/*.jar,${HADOOP_PREFIX}/share/hadoop/common/*.jar,${HADOOP_PREFIX}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar


    vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/conf>echo $HADOOP_PREFIX
/home/hduser/yarn/hadoop-2.4.0
```

I execute ./sqoop.sh server start..

```
Sqoop home directory: /home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200
Setting SQOOP_HTTP_PORT:     12000
Setting SQOOP_ADMIN_PORT:     12001
Using   CATALINA_OPTS:       
Adding to CATALINA_OPTS:    -Dsqoop.http.port=12000 -Dsqoop.admin.port=12001
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_15
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/bin/bootstrap.jar
vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/bin>

    vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/bin>netstat -aln | grep 12000
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
    vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/bin>
```

sqoop.war is deployed to webapps/sqoop

```
/lib:
total 4092
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop  160519 Oct 15  2013 commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop  279193 Oct 15  2013 commons-lang-2.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop   96221 Oct 15  2013 commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop    6734 Oct 18  2013 connector-sdk-1.99.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop 2671577 Oct 15  2013 derby-10.8.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop   16046 Oct 15  2013 json-simple-1.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop  481535 Oct 15  2013 log4j-1.2.16.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop  130387 Oct 18  2013 sqoop-common-1.99.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop   51382 Oct 18  2013 sqoop-connector-generic-jdbc-1.99.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop  119652 Oct 18  2013 sqoop-core-1.99.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop   70692 Oct 18  2013 sqoop-execution-mapreduce-1.99.3-hadoop200.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop   41462 Oct 18  2013 sqoop-repository-derby-1.99.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop   16156 Oct 18  2013 sqoop-spi-1.99.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop   16590 Oct 18  2013 sqoop-submission-mapreduce-1.99.3-hadoop200.jar
vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/webapps/sqoop/WEB-INF>
```

Then there are the logs:-

```
vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/logs>cat localhost.2014-05-11.log
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
    at org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine.initialize(MapreduceSubmissionEngine.java:78)
    at org.apache.sqoop.framework.JobManager.initialize(JobManager.java:215)
    at org.ap    vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/logs>ls -l
    total 24
    -rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop 3766 May 11 10:15 catalina.2014-05-11.log
    -rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop 8629 May 11 10:15 catalina.out
    -rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop    0 May 11 10:15 host-manager.2014-05-11.log
    -rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop 5032 May 11 10:15 localhost.2014-05-11.log
    -rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hadoop    0 May 11 10:15 manager.2014-05-11.log
    vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/logs>

-------------localhost*.log --------------

ache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:53)
    at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextInitialized(ServerInitializer.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 28 more

May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.sqoop.framework.JobManager.destroy(JobManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.destroy(SqoopServer.java:36)
    at org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer.contextDestroyed(ServerInitializer.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)


-----------------------catalina log ----------------------------

vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/logs>cat catalina.2014-05-11.log
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/${HADOOP_PREFIX}/share/hadoop/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/${HADOOP_PREFIX}/share/hadoop/mapreduce], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 399 ms
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive sqoop.war
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/sqoop] startup failed due to previous errors
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] appears to have started a thread named [sqoop-config-file-poller] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@3f782da8]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@6495dc5a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@3f782da8]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@3e8a0821]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1656 ms
vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/logs>

--------------------- catalina.out -------------------------

vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/logs>cat catalina.out
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/${HADOOP_PREFIX}/share/hadoop/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/${HADOOP_PREFIX}/share/hadoop/mapreduce], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 399 ms
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
May 11, 2014 10:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive sqoop.war
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[WARN, file].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category root set to WARN
log4j: Parsing appender named "file".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "file".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} [%l] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "file".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [@LOGDIR@/sqoop.log].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [5].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [25MB].
log4j: setFile called: @LOGDIR@/sqoop.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "file" options.
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache.sqoop] with value=[DEBUG].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category org.apache.sqoop set to DEBUG
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache.sqoop=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache.derby] with value=[INFO].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category org.apache.derby set to INFO
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache.derby=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
log4j: Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?
log4j: Parsing for [default] with value=[INFO,defaultAppender].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category default set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "defaultAppender".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "defaultAppender".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d %-5p %c: %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "defaultAppender".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [@LOGDIR@/default.audit].
log4j: setFile called: @LOGDIR@/default.audit, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "defaultAppender" options.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.default=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/sqoop] startup failed due to previous errors
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] appears to have started a thread named [sqoop-config-file-poller] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@3f782da8]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@6495dc5a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/sqoop] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@3f782da8]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@3e8a0821]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
log4j: log4j called after unloading, see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#unload.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class invariant violation
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLoggerRepository(LogManager.java:199)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:228)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
    at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcImportInitializer.<clinit>(GenericJdbcImportInitializer.java:42)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:949)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:930)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesStaticFinal(WebappClassLoader.java:2066)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:1929)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1833)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stop(WebappLoader.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4920)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12000
May 11, 2014 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1656 ms
vmcentos01:/home/hduser/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/logs>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as yours, and I found out you need to include all jars in your hadoop installation's share/hadoop folder. An example is that you have included `share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar`, but missed out `share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*.jar` one level deeper. Here is my `common.loader` setting that works (just swap out the hadoop location prefix):

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/../lib/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/tools/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*.jar,/localdisk/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*.jar
```

Comment: This solved my problem with sqoop2 1.99.6 and Hadoop 2.7.2 . I have added Hive jars to the end like `... ,/usr/local/hive/lib/*.jar` . It printed _Verification was successful._ message but with _JDBCREPO_0009:Failed to finalize transaction_ . This JDBC related thing is not important for verification purposes i think.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using Hadoop 2.4.0. Have you tried adding all hadoop jars (just add all jars existing in the folders in: share/hadoop/*) into the sqoop lib folder?

This finally made my sqoop server run (but in an earlier version). It is not the most perfect way to solve this, but at least you re able to run sqoop.

Maybe this will fix your problem.

Comment: No I've been avoiding that - but now is the time to try - common.loader doesn't work whatever I do with it  -thanks

Comment: I added all the jars I could find to the cataline erver/lib directory - complained about log4 and some others missing - added those too - now back to the original ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay -I had to put this issue down  - had a production issue. When I left it it was not working. I guess soon it will be time to get frustrated again..

Answer (score 0):

Using sqoop2 1.99.6 and Hadoop-2.7.1, I suffered this faith

```
root@some_server sqoop2]# sqoop2-tool verify
Setting conf dir: /sw/apache/sqoop2/bin/../conf
Sqoop home directory: /sw/apache/sqoop2
Sqoop tool executor:
    Version: 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    Revision: 81778c37a413eb64aa38ffc397af2ca695909013
    Compiled on Thu Dec 10 22:20:08 WAT 2015 by root
Running tool: class org.apache.sqoop.tools.tool.VerifyTool
0    [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer  - Initializing Sqoop server.
17   [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.core.PropertiesConfigurationProvider  -    Starting config file poller thread
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
at org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.SimpleAuthenticationHandler.secureLogin(SimpleAuthenticationHandler.java:36)
at org.apache.sqoop.security.AuthenticationManager.initialize(AuthenticationManager.java:98)
at org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.initialize(SqoopServer.java:55)
at org.apache.sqoop.tools.tool.VerifyTool.runTool(VerifyTool.java:36)
at org.apache.sqoop.tools.ToolRunner.main(ToolRunner.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Solution,
I tried the "common.loader" property approach , but for some reason I didn't get it right. 
In the end I copied all my hadoop jar files in my 
    $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop 
and 
    $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop*/lib/  to the $SQOOP2_HOME/server/lib.

```
[root@vggdw01 sqoop2]# cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/*.jar  server/lib/
cp: overwrite ‘server/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar’? n
cp: overwrite ‘server/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar’? n
cp: overwrite ‘server/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar’? n
cp: overwrite ‘server/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar’? n
cp: overwrite ‘server/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar’? n
cp: overwrite ‘server/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar’? n
cp: overwrite ‘server/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar’? n
cp: overwrite ‘server/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar’? n
```

I didn't override some jar files as seen above .

I figured if it was a TOMCAT thingy ... so I had to resort to these tactics.

Answer (score 0):

I am on HAdoop 2.6.2 and Sqoop 1.99.6, did the below

```
 edit $SQOOP_HOME/server/conf/catalina.properties
 modified common.loader and set the paths to my hadoop and hive dir's
```

(or) a lazy fix (as sudo) -

```
ln -s $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common /usr/lib/hadoop 
ln -s $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs 
ln -s $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce 
ln -s $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn 
mkdir -p /usr/lib/hive
chmod 775 /usr/lib/hive
ln -s $HIVE_HOME/lib /usr/lib/hive/lib
```

Also, modified org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine.mapreduce.configuration.directory property in SQOOP_HOME/server/conf/sqoop.properties and set that to a proper hadoop conf dir.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

since this problem is related to the fact that sqoop is not bein able to find automatically the hadoop configurations and libraries.
I pointed to the absolute path to those libraries

Below is my .profile file, after cen verify that everything is fine with:
sqoop2-tool verify

---

```
#SQOOP settings
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/sqoop
export SQOOP_CONF_DIR=$SQOOP_HOME/conf
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
SQOOP_SERVER_EXTRA_LIB=/var/lib/sqoop2

#Hadoop settings
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs
export YARN_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
#export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
```